# Gnuplot exponential function up to a certain y value

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a function f(x)=exp(-x+10) with the y-values below (and including) y=1. So basically in the range x>=10.

Trying

```
f(x) = x>=10 ? exp(-x+10) : 1/0
plot f(x)
```

does not work, because gnuplot starts plotting at y-values greater than 1. Shifting the interval a bit, I can also manage to start at values less than 1, however it seems impossible to hit exactly 1.

I presume this has something to do with precision which causes problems with the steep slope of the exponential.

Still, is there a way to properly plot that function in the specified range?

Comment: `So basically in the range x>=10.` soo `set xrange [10:*]`?

Comment: Unfortunately I still have other functions to the left of 10.

Comment: @KamilCuk this will lead to: `Warning: empty y range [1:1], adjusting to [0.99:1.01]
         x_min should not equal x_max!` at least with gnuplot 5.2.6

Comment: So you can specify range for each plot . `plot [10:*] exp(-x+10), [-10:10] 2*x`. `empty y range [1:1]` so change your yrange.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? I guess you have to set a xrange *including* an end.

```
reset session
f(x) = exp(-x+10)
set xrange[10:15]  
plot f(x)
```

[image]